# Publish message from the command line

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to send a `cmd_pos` message using the command line. The type of the message is `igntion::msgs::Double`. I am using the command

```
ign topic -t "world/empty/model/simple-robot/joint/the_joint/cmd_pos" -p "1.3" --msgtype ignition::msgs::Double`
```

instead of "1.3", I also tried 1.3, data: 1.3, {data: 1.3}, and more. But I keep getting the message

```
Unable to create message of type[ignition::msgs::Double] with data[...]
```

with my value for `p` on the `...`.

How can I send a Double message using the command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28581/publish-message-from-the-command-line/) by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116556/wilco-bonestroo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found out that the syntax should be `ign topic -t "/the_topic" -m ignition.msgs.Double -p "data: 0.5"` So using dots instead of double colons.

---

Originally posted by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116556/wilco-bonestroo/) with karma: 1 on 2022-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0